# Switch to 2 columns view shortcut not working Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, ubuntu-17.04

I have sublime text 3 (build 3131).I am using Single column view in my editor.Now I want to switch to 2 column view using <kbd>alt+shift+2</kbd> shortcut.However this is not working.I am using Ubuntu 17.04 budgie remix.Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It seems that unity was eating shift keypress event so now it is fixed

Comment: Works fine for me with ST3 build 3139 (latest dev build) on Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04.5). I very much doubt the Linux version makes any difference. 3139 is working perfectly on Linux why don't you try that and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Do `sublime.log_input(True)` in the sublime console and then press the key. If you don't see anything appear, the window manager is eating the key before Sublime even gets to see it, so you need to configure your machine not to use those keys for whatever it's trying to do. If you do see input, then some plugin has probably remapped the key on you, in which case `sublime.log_commands(True)` from the console and pressing the key will tell you what it's trying to do, which may help track it down. Probably the first one, though.

Comment: yes something is eating my shift key cause i only get `alt+2` and as a command I get THE `select_by_index`

Comment: Finaly it seems to be a problem with unity which I fixed.Thanks